# How to check a string that not empty in java?

Tags: java, android

How to check a string in java that is empty or not?

For example :
`string str = "   "` and `string str2 = " "` and `str3 = ""`

str includes 3 spaces, str2 includes 1 space, and str3 has no characters but all of them are empty.

How do I check this in Android?

Comment: They are both equal to some string and null at the same time?

Comment: Please clarify _but all of them are null_.

Comment: THey are not null.  They are empty.  There's a big difference.

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty() ?

Comment: In fact null is empty string

Comment: No @Programmer NULL and empty are two separate concepts in Java.  Learn that quickly or you'll be both confused and writing buggy code

Comment: Empty string `""` , string with spaces `"  "` and `null` string are 3 different things

Comment: @ShrikantHavale  but is differnet for me.how i do?

Comment: well your question is marked as duplicate and it indeed is, and answer to your question can be found at the top , where it says `This question already has an answer here:`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can see if the characters match

```
if (str.equals ("")) {
  // true
}

if (str3.equals ("   ")) {
  // true
}
```

Comment: Think I misunderstood his question...

Comment: I guess so, question is not clear, if he wants to compare empty strings or null strings

Comment: You can always edit or delete your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just check with `str.isEmpty()` as `isEmpty()` method will return true for actual length if 0.

As **NULL** refers to memory assignment of your `String str`. To check empty String use `isEmpty()` method.

**Update:**

In your case, best scenario should be,

```
if(str != null && str.trim().length() > 0)
{
     // String str is not NULL or not Empty
}else
{
    // String str is NULL or Empty
}
```

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis - Woops Its my Mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Null != empty.
Null means the variable is not initialized, like:
String s;
Your str,str2 and str3 are initialized, zo they are not null.

To check for same characters:
str.equals("foo"), ("foo" is in your case spaces :) )

NOT str == "foo". The last means you're checking same references.